# JS check site for classname and swap color of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to check my template for a class and swap the color of my text. It's a parallax template which contains slides with background-images+text and without+text. If there is no background-image, swap the text-color to black. If there is a background-image, swap the text-color to white.

You will find 3 news with background-images and 1 without in my div cluster:

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 abschnitt" id="abschnitt-0">
  <div class="section views-fieldset" data-module="views_fieldsets" style="margin-top: 194.5px;">
    <div>
      <h1> <a href="/drupal/node/4">Headline 1</a> </h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="body_text" id="body_text-0">
        <p> Newstext </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-holder views-fieldset" data-module="views_fieldsets" id="bg-holder-0">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="bg-holder bg-image" style="background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image/wallhaven-157066.jpg?itok=2BHBQSVa);" id="bg-image-0"> &nbsp; </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 abschnitt" id="abschnitt-1">
  <div class="section views-fieldset" data-module="views_fieldsets" style="margin-top: 194.5px;">
    <div>
      <h1> <a href="/drupal/node/3">Headline 2</a> </h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="body_text" id="body_text-1">
        <p>Newstext 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-holder views-fieldset" data-module="views_fieldsets" id="bg-holder-2">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="bg-holder bg-image" style="background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image/wallhaven-163460.jpg?itok=VnecbBnE);" id="bg-image-1"> &nbsp; </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 abschnitt" id="abschnitt-2">
  <div class="section views-fieldset" data-module="views_fieldsets" style="margin-top: 194.5px;">
    <div>
      <h1> <a href="/drupal/node/2">Headline 3</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="body_text" id="body_text-2">
        <p>Newstext 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-holder views-fieldset" data-module="views_fieldsets" id="bg-holder-4">
    <div>
      <div> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-4 abschnitt" id="abschnitt-3">
  <div class="section views-fieldset" data-module="views_fieldsets" style="margin-top: 194.5px;">
    <div>
      <h1><a href="/drupal/node/1">Headline 4</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="body_text" id="body_text-3">
        <p>Newstext 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-holder views-fieldset" data-module="views_fieldsets" id="bg-holder-5">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="bg-holder bg-image" style="background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image/wallhaven-18326.jpg?itok=M7ZCMtbM);" id="bg-image-2"> &nbsp; </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now Im trying to catch all cluster with class="bg-image" to change the color of my unique class="body-text-NUMBER" in reverse.

My try with JS:

```
 var bt_elems = document.getElementsByClassName("body_text");
    for (var i = 0, n = bt_elems.length; i<n; ++i){
        document.getElementsByClassName('body_text')[i].setAttribute('id', 'body_text-'+[i]);

        var el = document.getElementById('bg-image-'+[i]);
            if (el){
                console.log(document.getElementById('bg-image-'+[i]));
                console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('body_text')[i]);
                document.getElementsByClassName('body_text')[i].setAttribute('style', 'color: white;');
                console.log("#######");
            }else{
                document.getElementsByClassName('body_text')[i].setAttribute('style', 'color: black;');
            }
    };
```

It's working in some kind of way... but I can't figure it out how to swap the text-color of the RIGHT body-text-NUMBER.

**https://jsfiddle.net/ex43q7f7/6/**

Comment: I was going to fix your html presentation but it doesn't seem to be valid HTML. You need to check and make sure the part that was copied is correct.

Comment: Uhm, whats wrong with my html? I just copied that part from my template and replaced the news-text + headline.

Comment: When I fix html/js code presentation I run it in jsfiddle and hit the tidy button. Jsfiddle shows in red the faults in your html. I removed them and tried making it look better. If this is what it's supposed to look like feel free to copy it and update your html: http://jsfiddle.net/dd8cmdev/2/

If not find a way to tidy your html. A lot of users won't bother trying to read it when it's hard to read.

**Edit**: That looks much better btw

Comment: I'm very sorry for that "div-rampage". Drupal is creating this mess. I fixed/tidy the HTML Part and edited the jsfiddle-link :)

Answer (score 1):

the counter of body_text id's do not match the counter of your bg-image id's

Under body_text_2 there is no bg-image present but you search for bg-image_2, this DOES exists but is located under body_text_3.

jsfiddle.net/ex43q7f7/7 here is with the body_text id numbers matching the bg-image id numbers, then it works.

So, if no image you should still add the id counter +1 so that they match up

Comment: Unfortunately not. The third Newstext should be black, the others white. I updated the jsfiddle. Now you can see the Headlines with bg-images. https://jsfiddle.net/ex43q7f7/6/

Comment: the counter of body_text id's do not match the counter of your bg-image id's ...... so when there is a body_text without a bg-image, the next body_text[n] has to search for a  bg-image[n-1]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ex43q7f7/7/   here is with the body_text id numbers matching the bg-image id numbers, then it works.

Comment: I edited my answer, just fix it so that the numbering of the id's match ;)

Comment: Oh lord. Okay, now I understand. I have to fix the body_text and bg-image id numbers.